# Admob is load failing by No Fill error

Tags: unity, admob

I’m using official admin plugin for Unity implementing Reward video.

But it’s only working for test unit id, when I replacing it to my own unit id, it just failing load by error “No Fill”.

Even when I add test device, still happening the issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: i have same problem... How can solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not resolved, I moved to Unity Ads =/